# Trail slash is causing 404 error and improper url behavior: APACHE/ PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, trailing-slash

Hoping one of you can help. I am developing using php, without a framework, therefore all of my routing rules are in .htaccess as opposed to .php

So here is my problem. Say my website is http://example.com and my navigation is pretty straight forward, meaning if you click the 'press' page link you will go to http://example.com/press or http://example.com/press/ which are both fine.

However, if you do happen to go to http://example.com/press/ click another internal link in my nav, such as 'about' etc.. I will not take you to '/example' but rather '/press/example' which shows a 404 since there is not page or directory to handle this.

I tried 'DirectorySlash Off' in my .htaccess but all that did was prevent any of these pages from showing if a url has / at the end.

I have a very basic .htaccess setup, See below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
# Options -Indexes
# GEN CONFIG



# Handle Errors
ErrorDocument 403 /views/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /views/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 303 /views/errors/404.php

# Url renamin
RewriteRule ^(about-us|About-Us|ABOUT-US)/?$ views/about-us.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(press|Press|PRESS)/?$ views/press.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(faq|Faq|FAQ)/?$ views/faq.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> go to `http://example.com/press/` click another internal link in my nav, such as `about` etc.. I will not take you to `/about` but rather `/press/about`

This problem is not due to rewrite rules but due to your use of relative paths.

To fix, you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Although I thought the same thing, and tried that method earlier, it keeps appending the next link to the trailing slash at the end.

Comment: Also just to further my point, if you go to http://example.com/press/ and click another link it just appends it to the end of the trailing slash.

Comment: Yes that is what the behavior will be if you use relative links instead of absolute ones. Absolute paths start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it seems './' or just the page name like 'about-us' was causing this, however as soon as I added '/about-us' it was resolved.. However I dont know why some page urls will still accept a trailing slash at the end but other wont?

Comment: All of your rules have optional trailing slash so there shouldn't be any problem of having or not having it. `404` while clicking next **valid** link is always due to relative paths being used.

Comment: yes it is thank you! I must improve my REGEX abilities in order to need less help understanding these .htaccess files. You have been an Angel!